# Use of mkdir -v output with a newline embedded

Tags: bash

First of all, this question is purely theoric; it involves creates a directory with a newline, thing that should NEVER be done.

That said, I'm trying to use `mkdir -pv` output to remove the created directories in a specific moment of my script, but only the newly created, not the ones that previously existed.

Command `mkdir -pv` will print one line per directory not-existent before this command call so that I can re-inject in a `rm -rf` command. It works OK except in the case that directory contains a newline, and I can't see what is wrong with it.

My minimal working example:

```
declare -a created
# Delete previous traces
mkdir_out=$(mkdir -pv 'new 10'{1,2,3,$'\n',"'a",4})

# Convert to array
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a created < <(printf '%s' "${mkdir_out}")

# Debug
printf '=>[1] %s\n' "${created[@]}"

# We only want content between first and last quote
created=( "${created[@]%[\'\"]}" )
created=( "${created[@]#*[\'\"]}" )

# Debug
printf '=>[2] %s\n' "${created[@]}"

rm -rfv "${created[@]}"
ls  # Directory "new 10\n" is still there!!
```

So, what is the safe way to do that?

Comment: That's not a newline, that's a literal `\n`.

Comment: "I'm trying to use mkdir -pv output to remove", why, use the arguments that you pass to `mkdir` instead.

Comment: Sorry @Josh-lee, you are right, I paste the wrong mkdir parameters. Editing.

Comment: Hi, @Dzienny. If I use the same parameters that with `mkdir`, rm will delete all my directory: the ones that script created, and the ones that were already created.

Comment: What if you try with `ls -b` or `ls --escape`? I remember that you want use the output of `mkdir -v` but the output of ls command is more reliable.

Comment: This is not purely theoretic; a script that cannot handle a legal file name is buggy, period.

Comment: @jsxt, if I parse the `ls` output, I'm not able to recognize the newly created ones and the already created.

Comment: @chepner, I was trying to say that I will never use in production, was just a hardening test that (should) never happen in real code.

Comment: But again, the problem is not with directories with newlines in their names; the problem is with code that *assumes* a newline will never be used. Early shells made a design tradeoff to make typing commands as simple as possible in some cases, at the expense of making it hard to correctly handle *all* cases. We're still paying for that decision decades later. Even if you don't expect to use such names, your code should still be resilient to an "adversary" who uses them either accidentally or intentionally.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you, @chepner. I forgot to say that I control the created directories, i.e., they will not be user-introduced, but yes, someday some other programmer (like the future me) will need to introduce a newline and it will blow. So I would probably go with "that other gay" solution, just for sanity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output like `mkdir: created directory 'foo'` is only meant for humans. Don't try to parse it.

If you want to handle all possible filenames and you can't deal in `\0` separated lists, you have to do them one by one. Here's an example:

```
declare -a created dirs

dirs=( 'new 10'{1,2,3,$'\n',"'a",4} )

created=()
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
  if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]] && mkdir -p "$dir"
  then
    created+=( "$dir" )
  fi
done

rm -rfv "${created[@]}"
ls  # Directory "new 10\n" is not there.
```

Comment: Cool, that was going to be my first choice. Just for curiosity, is there any way to "re-escape" or parse the newline in the output?

Comment: There's no good standard way, but `bash` provides two. The first is to use the `%q` format with `printf`; the second (introduced recently, in 4.4) is to use `${foo@Q}` as the parameter expansion.